# Using 'IN' to compare Date - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that I need to filter based on date. For my problem, I have to filter the record which are relevant only for the current date without the time portion of the date.

For that I have used the following approach. Query seems to be working fine but I would like to know whether there are any pitfalls in this approach.Part of the `WHERE` clause related to the query is as follows.

```
AND TO_CHAR(EOD_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') IN TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

EOD_DATE is the field in the table I take into consideration.I want records that EOD_DATE value is in the current date regardless of the time portion of EOD_DATE.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATE` datatype is up to a second precise. Therefore:

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) d_from, trunc(sysdate + 1) - 1/(24*60*60) d_to from dual;

D_FROM              D_TO
------------------- -------------------
21.06.2018 00:00:00 21.06.2018 23:59:59
```

says that - if you want to be able to use index on the EOD_DATE column - you should consider

```
where eod_date between trunc(sysdate)
                   and trunc(sysdate + 1) - 1/(24*60*60)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution works, but you are using a double conversion to compare strings instead of comparing dates. Besides, you don't need `IN` but an `=`

This could be a better, more readable way:

```
... and trunc(sysdate) = trunc(EOD_DATE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `TRUNC` to remove the time component (or rather set it to `00:00:00`) and then compare the dates:

```
WHERE TRUNC(EOD_DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```